# Case sensitive folder names in OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, filesystems, hfs

I have two folders on a Tomcat server:

```
linkredirect

LINKredirect
```

(*I know it is bad practice to use upper case, but it is out of my control*)

Both directories are hosted on the server and there is no problem.

The problem arises when I need to store them on a SVN. When I try hosting both folders in the same directory, they overwrite each other, because they have the same name.

Is there any way of changing OS X so that file/folder names are case sensitive?

Comment: Requiring case-sensitive client file systems is just as bad (read: platform dependent) as non-ascii filenames and is probably not the best idea for long-term use of SVN, which can be used on Mac OS X, Linux, and Windows. Just a thought.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HFS+ supports both case-sensitivity and case-insensitivity. You can select which when creating the partition in `Disk Utility.app`. Some applications (infamously: Adobe products) break when you switch to case sensitivity.

To clarify: You would need to reformat the disk. It's not some switch hidden in System Preferences or anything like that.

Comment: I'd recommend putting the repository on a separate volume from the OS, and formatting just that as case-sensitive HFS+.  BTW, I haven't used it, but [iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php) claims to be able to convert between normal & case-sensitive HFS+ without reformatting.

Comment: Technically, HFS+ does not support case sensitive file names, but HFSX (supported by Mac OS X 10.3+) does.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#HFSX

Answer (score 2):

To get case sensitivity you're going to need to switch the file system from HFS+ to UFS.

This [article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1410) briefly explains the differences.

Comment: It is not even possible to format disks as UFS in Disk Utility.

Comment: My mistake, looks like after 10.4 only OS X Server supports UFS.
There should be a case sensitive HFS+ option, but I don't have my mac right now to check.  Either way, it requires a reformat.